# How do I assign a new element of an object in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, variable-assignment

```
@comments = []

@preComments = Comment.where(:resource_hash => resource_hash).
                       sort(:created_at.desc).all

@preComments.each do |comment|
  newComment = comment
  u = ::User.find_by_id comment.user_id

  newComment.display_name = "Some name"

  if u.image_location.nil?
    newComment.image_location = "defaultpic"
  else
    newComment.image_location = u.image_location
  end

    p u

    @comments << newComment

    p "HERE!!!!!"
  end
```

That's my code, but I get an error saying

```
undefined method `display_name=' for #
```

So how do I assign a `display_name`?

Comment: Is display_name a field of `Comment` or `User` ?

Comment: Well.. It's part of `User` which is an `EmbeddedDocument` of `Comment`. I'm using Mongo_Mapper

Comment: I dont't know how to use MongoMapper but I think that you have to access it by `newComment.user.display_name`

Comment: What if I don't want it as part of a model... I just want to add a parameter to the object? Is that not possible in Rails?

Comment: Not in standard rails, because it relies on relational DB. In pure Ruby, you have to declare at least a field with `attr_accessor :display_name` in your model class. You should take a look at MongoMapper doc, maybe is there some method to add a property on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclosure : I've never use MongoMapper

So my best bet is : just add `display_name` as part of the `Comment` schema. In models/comment.rb :

```
class Comment
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :display_name,  String
  key ...
  [...]
```

end